# LZ4Net.Wrap results to larger string when compressing base64 string

Tags: c#, lz4

I'm using lz4net to compress messages between my webapi. I'm converting an image from a stream to a base64 string in the client then send it to the web api. Before storage, I try to compress the string to save space using lz4net. The resulting string is longer than the original base64 string. I'd like help on figuring out why that is. Thank you.

Code:

```
 byte[] arRegistration = oImgBrowser.mGetByteArray(oRegistrationStream);
 sRegistrationImage = Convert.ToBase64String(arRegistration);
 oRegistrationStream = new MemoryStream(arRegistration);
 sRegistrationImage = mCompressString(sRegistrationImage)


 public static string mCompressString(string sData)
        {
            string sCompressedString = "";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sData))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The input data cannot be null");
            }
            byte[] arData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sData);
            sCompressedString = Convert.ToBase64String(LZ4Codec.Wrap(arData));
            return sCompressedString;
        }
```

Comment: Show us the code you're using

Comment: I've updated the post with my code